# Form Submission to multiple Domain objects in Grails

Tags: grails

I am very much a newbie to Grails. I am learning a basic CRUD operation. Here I have 2 domain object Person and Address. Each Person only needs to have only one Address

So I have a gsp form which collects username, first name, last name, age and address fields and should store into basically 2 tables in database Person and Address. So how write the code in the controllers which maps 2 domain classes(Person & Address).

Thanks for answering.

UPDATE: I used the following code which didnt work

```
package com.deltaintech.wr

class Person {
    String username
    String password
    String firstname
    String lastname
    String email
    Address address

    static constraints = {
    }
}


package com.deltaintech.wr

class Address {

    String address1
    String address2
    String city
    String state
    String country
    String zipcode

    static constraints = {
    }
}

package com.deltaintech.wr.register
import com.deltaintech.wr.*

class RegisterController {

    def index = { 

    }

    def register = {

        Person person = new Person(params)
        person.save()

    }
}

<!--
  To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
  and open the template in the editor.
-->

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Sample title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sample line</h1>
  <g:form action="register">
   User Name <g:textField name="username"/><br>
   Password <g:passwordField name="password" /><br>
   First Name <g:textField name="firstname"/><br>
   Last Name <g:textField name="lastname"/><br>
   Email <g:textField name="email" /><br>
   Address1 <g:textField name="address.address1"/><br>
   Address2 <g:textField name="address.address2" /><br>
   City <g:textField name="address.city" /><br>
    State<g:textField name="address.state" /><br>
    Country <g:textField name="address.country" /><br>
   Zip Code <g:textField name="address.zipcode" /><br>
    <g:submitButton name="create" value="Create"/>
  </g:form>
</body>
</html>


Error 500: Executing action [register] of controller [com.deltaintech.wr.register.RegisterController] caused exception: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.deltaintech.wr.Person.address; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.deltaintech.wr.Person.address
Servlet: grails
URI: /system/grails/register/register.dispatch
Exception Message: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.deltaintech.wr.Person.address 
Caused by: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.deltaintech.wr.Person.address 
Class: RegisterController 
At Line: [13]
```

Comment: i think that i forgot something. try following: add static belongsTo = [person: Person] to the address domain class. that creates an bidirectional relation between person and address which is required for saving two domain classes in the same time. if you do not want this, you can do following in controller class: Address adr = new Address(params.address); Person person = new Person(params); person.address = adr.save();

Answer (score 2):

```
class Person { 
    String name 
    Address address 
} 

class Address { 
   String city 
}
```

the gsp has to look somethink like:

```
<g:form action="save">
    <g:textField name="name"/>
    <g:textField name="address.city"/>
</g:form>
```

in the controller:

```
def p = new Person(params)
p.save()
```